# Python shows 'library not loaded'

Tags: python, dyld

I am trying to simply install a new module. But it kept giving me errors. I have both python27 and python36 on Mac. I am using python27 when this happened. I could not run either pip or conda.

After I run:
     pip install regions

I got these errors:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/yan/anaconda/bin/python
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/yan/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython3.6m.dylib: file too short
Abort trap: 6
```

And another relevant question, if I installed some modules when using python36, could I import these in python27? Do I need to reinstall those? Thanks!!!

Comment: Looks like your libs got corrupted somehow?

Comment: Probably. But I don't know. It is still looking for lib under anaconda directory and finds the named library. But somehow it is the wrong one. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, not all modules are compatible with Anaconda Python (as I can see from the log, you use it). The problem like this also appears for
`virtualenv`. But `regions` documentation indicates [the way to install](https://github.com/astropy/regions/blob/master/docs/installation.rst#using-conda) it with `conda`.

> Using conda To install regions with Anaconda from the astropy channel
>   on anaconda.org simply run:
>
> conda install -c astropy regions

And about the second question - no, modules should be installed separately for Python 2 and 3

Comment: Thank you. I tried conda as well. It is the same error.

Comment: conda install -c astropy regions
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/yan/anaconda/bin/python
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Users/yan/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython3.6m.dylib: file too short
Abort trap: 6

Comment: what OS do you use and what architecture? Maybe the module is not compatible with your python build?

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Solved. The path got messed up. Just look up the path by "echo $PATH" and carefully changed it to the python I want to use. It is not good when everything you download comes with their version of python.